# jQuery-Form-Validator(plugin) and preventDefault

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the following [form-validator plugin](http://formvalidator.net/index.html) and I have the following situation which creates problems.

When my submit button is clicked I want to preventDefault behaviour because I am making an ajax call to a php script to insert the data and I don't want the page to reload.

The problem is that the Validation does not work when I preventDefault() on my button.

I tried to use the onSuccess callback that is descripted [here](http://formvalidator.net/index.html#configuration_callbacks) but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to perform Validation in the form **and** preventDefault behaviour?

Comment: validation is likely bound to submit event so blocking default of button makes no sense. What does `doesn't work` mean regarding `onSuccess`?

Comment: I tried to make my ajax call inside the onSuccess callback function, but it doesn't work.

So there is no way to mix the two? Validate and make an ajax call?

Comment: should work unless you have other errors and you need to prevent default submit from that callback also

Comment: Thanks it worked now, I forgot to add the return false; at the end :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is my validate function, for future reference

```
$.validate({
    form: '#addUserForm',
    onSuccess: function() {

        dataString = $('#addUserForm').serialize()+'&'+encodeURI("action")+'='+encodeURI("addUser");

        $.ajax({
            url: "addUser.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                $("<div class='infoBox'>"+data['message']+"</div>").hide().prependTo("#mainContent").fadeIn("slow").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow", function(){location.reload();});
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error on adding User");
            }

        })
        return false;
    }
});
```